# How to configure Content Security Policy in WordPress for this reported issue (image-src)?

Tags: wordpress, content-security-policy

I am receiving this Consent Security Policy error (or warning) on my website:

> [Report Only] Refused to load the image '' because it violates
> the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:
> s.w.org ps.w.org ts.w.org secure.gravatar.com  
> stats.g.doubleclick.net translate.googleapis.com translate.google.com
>   i.ytimg.com".

I am testing this using Microsoft Edge on Windows 11. In my WordPress setup I have it configured to use GD Security Header plugin. This is how I have the thirdparty rules setup:

[image]

And further down (for `image-src`) I don't have any custom entries yet:

[image]

It is not clear to me what I shoudl be adding for the above report I am receiving. The webpage in question:

https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/

---

I see that if I expand the tag in the console that it lists the URLs in question:

- https://marketingweek.imgix.net/content/uploads/2018/04/31103255/iStock-538980989-e1527759223230.jpg
- https://img.youtube.com/vi/ZV4b5Ps3C_s/mqdefault.jpg
- https://img.youtube.com/vi/nWeSnf7sl84/sddefault.jpg
- https://help-msa.publictalksoftware.co.uk/lib/DLG_MSA.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I added the following:

[image]

I think this has resolved the console issues that I was having.